# Can't cast app.fragment to my custom fragment ModelFragment using FragmentManager

Tags: android

The `ModelFragment` is saying inconvertible types and giving me the following error and it cannot resolve method.

> cannot cast android.app.fragment to ModelFrament

```
 if (adapter==null) {
            ModelFragment mfrag=
                    (ModelFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MODEL);

            if (mfrag==null) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(new ModelFragment(), MODEL).commit();
            }
            else if (mfrag.getBook()!=null) {
                setupPager(mfrag.getBook());
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show your `ModelFragment` class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `ModelFragment` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. In that case, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: You can rewrite it with import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment` so person will understand better.